# How to make the rest of code wait in fun1 until fun2() finishes, where fun2 is a nested function in fun1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```
fun1()
{
 for()     //fun1 making api calls in loop
 {
  https.get()
  {
    ..
    ..
    fun2();   //Invoking fun2
    fu2()
    {
      for()   //fun2 also making api calls in loop
     {
      https.get()
      {
        ..
        ..
      }
    }}
  }
}
}
```

the code is running asynchronosly, how can i make it run in line by line, means when untill fun2() code completes the rest of code in fun1 not have to execute . fun1 has to wait untill fun2 complets.

Iam thinking this will be resolved by async-await but dont know how to do it. could anyone help me plaese

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a loop.

```
async function fun1() {
  async function fun2() {
  //...
  }
  await Promise.all([...Array(10).keys()].map((i) => { fun2() })
}
```

but if you really love your loop

```
async function fun1() {
  async function fun2() {
  //...
  }
  const promises = []
  for(...) {
    promises.push(fun2())
  }
  await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vulwsztyn,
Thanks for helping me on this issue. 
But the solution which u provided, that iam not able to insert properly into my code and also i didn't asked asked the ques with proper code. 


Here is the my code which iam using. In this code Iam using three console.log's for printing

1.console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
2.console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);
3. console.log("result="+result)

If iam able to get the output in this order 

console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5); 
console.log("result="+result);
console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);
console.log("result="+result);
...
....
...

then i can assure my code is running sequentially.

Could u please edit this code with async.await, bcoz idont know much about async.await and where to add it correctly.

Normally iam getting o/p like this :

console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
console.log("result="+result)
console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);
console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);
console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);

Thank you
```

```
========CODE=======
//First Function

function getDetailsOfEachProxy(maxRevisionNumberOfEachApiArray,mailArray,hostName,reqHeaders,callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    for(z=0;z<mailArray.length;z++)   
        {
            let options = {
              hostname: hostName,
              path: "/v1/organizations/orgname/apis/"+mailArray[z]+"/revisions/"+maxRevisionNumberOfEachApiArray[z],
              method: "GET",
              headers: { 
                  "Authorization": reqHeaders
              }
            }
            https.get(options, (res) => {
              res.setEncoding('utf8');
              let data1='';
              res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data1 += chunk;
              })
              res.on('end', () => {    
                    jsonParsedArray2 = JSON.parse(data1);
                     console.log("Fun1 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray2);
                    for (key in jsonParsedArray2) {
                        if (jsonParsedArray2.hasOwnProperty(key))
                        {
                            listOfElementsArray[j] = jsonParsedArray2[key];
                            j=j+1;
                            var apiBasePath = listOfElementsArray[0];
                             var apiName = listOfElementsArray[11];
                            var apiProxies = listOfElementsArray[12];
                            var proxyEndPointElement = listOfElementsArray[13];
                            var proxyResources = listOfElementsArray[16];
                             var proxyRevision = listOfElementsArray[17];
                            var targetEnPointElement = listOfElementsArray[22];  
                        } 
                        }
                        for (key2 in apiProxies){
                            apiProxyArray[t] = apiProxies[key2];
                            t++;  
                            }
                        for (key2 in proxyEndPointElement){
                            var proxyEndPoint = proxyEndPointElement[key2];
                            }
                        for (key2 in proxyResources){
                            proxyResourcesArray[t2] = proxyResources[key2];
                            t2++;
                            rotation1++;   
                            }  
                        for (key2 in targetEnPointElement){
                            var targetEndPoint = targetEnPointElement[key2];
                            }
                                     
                for(i=0;i<apiProxyArray.length;i++)
                {
                f = apiProxyArray[i];
                if (f.startsWith('FC-'))
                {
                flowCalloutPolicyArray[fcpa] = f;
                fcpa++;
                }                  
                f='';
                }

                for(i=0;i<apiProxyArray.length;i++)
                {
                f2 = apiProxyArray[i];
                if(f2.startsWith('KVM-'))
                {
                kvmPolicyArray[kpa] = f2;
                kpa++;
                }                
                f2='';
                }
                            
//Invoking Second Fun inside First Fun        
   getSharedFlows(apiName,proxyRevision,hostName,reqHeaders,flowCalloutPolicyArray,function(result)
                        {
                 console.log("result="+result)
                            });

//Second Function

function getSharedFlows(apiName,proxyRevision,hostName,reqHeaders,flowCalloutPolicyArray,callback){ 
if(flowCalloutPolicyArray.length > 0)
{    
        for(iim=0;iim<flowCalloutPolicyArray.length;iim++)
        {
         let options = {
             hostname: hostName,
             path:  "/v1/organizations/orgname/apis/"+apiName+"/revisions/"+proxyRevision+"/policies/"+flowCalloutPolicyArray[iim],
             method: "GET",
             headers: { 
                 "Authorization": reqHeaders
             }
           }
           https.get(options, (res) => {
             res.setEncoding('utf8');
             let data4='';
             res.on('data', (chunk) => {
               data4 += chunk;
             })
             res.on('end', () => {    
                   jsonParsedArray5= JSON.parse(data4);
                  console.log("Fun2 Api Response======",jsonParsedArray5);
                    }) //res.on
                });//http.get
   }//for
          callback("successfully executing code line by line")
    }//if
    sfbv = 0;
 }//fun

 

                                j=0;
          
          flowCalloutPolicyArray.length=0;
          fcpa=0;
          apiProxyArray.length=0;
          t=0;
          proxyResourcesArray.length=0;
          t2=0;
          sharedFlowElement = '';
          //sharedFlowBundleValue ='';
          
          kvmPolicyArray.length = 0;
          kpa = 0;
          kvmElement = '';

          

  
            })//CLOSING INTERNAL res.on function
            // console.log('Number of developers having certficate=',certsArray.length)
            
          });//CLOSING INTERNAL https FUNCTION
          //LOOP ROTATE UPTO HERE ONLY 
               
        }//FOR LOOP END 
    },5500);  
}//END OF FUNCTION
```